# Contour plot for three vectors in R using rsm package

Tags: r, rstudio

I have the following code to construct a contour plot:

```
library(rsm)

x<-c(5.64,5.64,5.64,6.32,6.99,7.66,6.11,6.11,5.92,5.63)
y<-c(0.09,0.12,0.15,0.24,0.29,0.33,0.16,0.18,0.17,0.15)
z<-c(10.43,3.83,15.74,0,0,0,15.38,22.98,10.76,16.74)

z.lm <- lm(z ~ poly(x, y, degree=2))

contour(z.lm, x ~ y)
```

It runs great in plain vanilla R console and I can get the graph that I need. When I try to run the very same code in RStudio, the following error pops up:

> Error in contour.default(z.lm, x ~ y) : no proper 'z' matrix specified

Comment: I suspect the issue isn't to do with R Studio or R console. The error is reported from the `contour.default` function rather than the `contour.lm` function that the *rsm* package provides (I get the error you're seeing because I don't have *rsm* installed). Are you sure you loaded the package successfully when using both instances of R?

Comment: Indeed.  The rsm package was installed and loaded... I have no problem with that...

Answer (score 0):

Ran both in `R console` and in `Rstudio`, it is working fine.  Maybe, we need to do this on fresh session

[image]

Comment: This did the trick... Starting the session again worked fine and asked me to install rsm...  What I don't get is: how come rsm shows to be installed in the plain vanilla R and not in RStudio?  Beats me... But hey, thanks, restarting the session did the trick...

Comment: Check your `.libPaths()` both outside and inside RStudio. Check whether you are running the same versions of R, as packages are installed in a folder based on the minor version number (e.g. 4.0 and 4.1). Either way, RStudio is just a tool to better interact with R, it doesn't change R's behaviour.